# Can you toggle grouping in a Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, master-detail

Is it possible to have a report which has grouping on the underlying data but for which you can disable the grouping via a button or something on the report? Basically I want to have a "Summary Report" which is grouped, but then be able to view the detail beneath when required without having a separate report for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data in the group headers and footers, then have the detailed data in the details section. In the details section, set a formula on the suppress to be based on a report parameter. Then when you want a detailed report, pass in the parameter as false and it won't suppress the details section. You can toggle the header and footer of the groups this way too.

You cannot get rid of a grouping, but if you wanted to have something similar, you could use a field that you populate to group by. If you want the grouping, you fill in this field with the data you need to group by, and if you want the detail, just leave that field set to blank and then suppress the group header and footer.

Comment: I still have to run the report twice depending on whether I'm running in "Summary" or "Detail" mode, but it's better than two reports, Cheers!